# How to fire prompt modal on tab clicking twitter bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have nav tabs

```
<li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab">First Tab</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab">Second Tab</a></li>
```

I need to fire a modal with prompt like "Do you want to save changes before leave tab?"

```
<div id="prompt" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
                  aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        ...
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I've tried to rise it like

```
 $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {
                    $('#prompt').modal('show');

                });
```

But it doesn't wait for user react on Prompt.

How to make to tab clicking for waiting user's confirmation? if it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Check out this bootply](http://www.bootply.com/5wtgzTfaLs)

I used the modal on document load, but the same function `$('#myModal').modal();` launches your modal. I also included an on click function for when the user clicks the save button on the modal.

**jquery**

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#myModal').modal();
});

$('#save').click(function() {
            //whatever happens when you save
});
```

**HTML**

```
 <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button id="save" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To change this into tab clicks, add a class called clickSave to each tab, then use a function like the following to launch modal:

```
$(".clickSave").click(function(){
    $('#myModal').modal();
});
```

Then in the modal you toggle to the next tab on the click. Look [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) for how to do it using javascript.

**Overall Steps:**

1. On clicking a tab open a modal (you need to store what tab was clicked)
2. On clicking a modal button either close or save settings
3. Use stored tab and javascript to navigate to it

If you use this order of operations, the tab will not open until the user chooses to close or save.